# How many ways are there to do this so that there are 2 red cards and 3 black cards?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Suppose that 5 cards are taken without replacement from a deck of 52 cards.
Okay so this is one of my homework questions and I wanted to know if I was on the right track in terms of reasoning. So since both red and black suits are made of 26 cards each I decided to add them ${26 \choose 2} + {26 \choose 3} = 2925$

Comment: You should multiply, not add.

Comment: Imagine the deck consists of $5$ cards only: $2$ red cards and $3$ black cards. How many ways are there to pick $5$ cards our of this deck so that there are $2$ red cards and $3$ black cards? As silly as this question may sound, it has a point: compare the correct answer, which is pretty obvious, with what you'd get if you "decide to add them".

Comment: Okay thank you I don't know what I was thinking when I decided to add them instead of multiply them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for each pair of red cards you can have any of the sets of black cards, so you have to multiply.